# typescript - how to properly extend interface with some fields overrided

Tags: typescript

I want to extend the Interface `Position` and update the type of its fields

```
export interface Position {
  expiryDate: string;
  strike: string;
  ...
}

type OverridePosition = Omit<Position, 'expiryDate|strike'> & {
  expiryDate: number;
  strike: number;
}

let positionItem:OverridePosition = {
  expiryDate: 1000000,
  strike: 2000;
  ...
}
```

But error throw for `positionItem`.

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
Type.ts(37, 3): The expected type comes from property 'expiryDate' which is declared here on type 'OverridePosition'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close but you got the `Omit` wrong. The proeprty names to omit should be a union of strings, and not a single string with a pipe character.

```
type OverridePosition = Omit<Position, 'expiryDate' | 'strike'> & {
  expiryDate: number;
  strike: number;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2&ssl=6&ssc=1&pln=9&pc=2#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgBQgGcEYEIk4BvAKDjlDASgE8ARTVALjiJimQBzANx1e-BAGtgPPgKQiaAXxo0YLMHgDyANzQCAJsEIkyFOAF44WgLakAPCdLkkAGjgByRs3adgHuAAfTzkpfwA+OAAyajFvVg5uOCQAVxsAIzRRelDpHlSMrOVVABtgeEhTFwBJVBseXX0EIyczSitaenjfJIBGAAZBodcxXJk4ACZh5SA)